# C preprocessor, insert "# this is a comment" in a non C output file

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm using `cpp` to generate a configuration file for a window manager.

The configuration file syntax uses `"#"` to introduce comments,
the closest thing that I've found is

```
...
#ident "this is a comment"
...
```

that, when feed through `cpp`,  generates

```
...
#ident "this is a comment"
...
```

but I'd like to get

```
...
# this is a comment
...
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution w/r to `#ident ...`

```
#define coMMent(hash, c) hash c
...
coMMent(#, pippo si taglia)
...
```

gives

```
...
 # pippo si taglia
...
```

(note the blank in first column) that is close enough.

I'm still interested in the perfect (no blanks) solution...